# Json Parsing in Volley - Android using JSONObject

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have a simple json response:

{"result":"success","message":26}

where 26 is the id of the registered user.

Now I want to use json parsing in android so as to get that int value and store it in SharedPreferences.

So here is what I do.

```
 @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("Response", "Register Response: " + response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                if (jsonObject.getString("result").equals("success")) {

                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    int id = jsonObject.getInt("message");
                    Log.d("Theo", String.valueOf(id));

                    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

                    editor.putString("id", String.valueOf(id));
                    editor.putString("email", email);
                    editor.putString("user_name", userName);
                    editor.putString("user_pass", password);
                    editor.putString("confirm_pass", confirmPassword);

                    editor.commit();
                }

                else if (jsonObject.getString("result").equals("fail")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

I try to read this value with this line.

```
       int id = jsonObject.getInt("message");
```

But I read nothing.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: what issue you are facing exactly?

Comment: I get no int value!

Comment: try this, instead of this JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);    try this JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.quote(response); and proceed.

Comment: let me know if it works ?

Comment: it says: Required org.json.JSONObject,found java.lang.String;

Comment: it is a compiler error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117423/discussion-between-ragu-swaminathan-and-theo).